# Manually stopped service is not properly stopped

Tags: bash, systemd, socket, socket-activation

I have a Server, that is supposed to activate if someone tries to connect to it. For this I created a systemd socket and service that builds a proxy for my server and starts it. Thanks to [this Tutorial](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/docker-systemd-socket-activation/) it wasn't too hard.

I made a FIFO-Pipe to communicate with the running server and if nobody is active on it I want the server to stop. If I stop the Server through the pipe the Server.service stays in a `loaded deactivating stop` state while the proxy.service stays in the running. (state from `systemctl list-units`)

I want the Service to restart again if someone tries to connect again, but this only works if I manually `systemctl stop server.service`.

---

proxy.socket

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=25565

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

proxy.server

```
[Unit]
Requires=server.service
After=server.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd 127.0.0.1:25555
```

server.service

```
[Unit]
Description=my Server

[Service]
User=nonRootUser
ExecStart=/home/nonRootUser/server/startup-fifo.sh
ExecStop=/home/nonRootUser/server/cmd stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, even though it may be ugly.

Instead of let the proxy.service `Requires=server.service` i let the proxy.service `BindTo=server.service`.
This way the proxy.service properly ends itself if the server.service stops or fails.

Now the server.service was still running in the `loaded deactivating stop` state where it could not restart for some reason. I let the process fail after script completion with `exit 1`, so the server.service goes to the state `loaded failed failed`.

Because the proxy.service still requires the server.service it is restarted and everything is working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

`server.service` is of the `Type=simple` variety (the default if an `ExecStart=` is specified).

Regarding its `ExecStop=` there is an interesting tidbit in the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

> Note that the commands specified in ExecStop= are only executed when the service started successfully first. They are not invoked if the service was never started at all, or in case its start-up failed, for example because any of the commands specified in ExecStart=, ExecStartPre= or ExecStartPost= failed (and weren't prefixed with "-", see above) or timed out... ***Also note that the stop operation is always performed if the service started successfully, even if the processes in the service terminated on their own or were killed. The stop commands must be prepared to deal with that case.***

From your question it sounds like the `server.service` is terminating on its "own" (rather, via your sending content over the FIFO). systemd will see this and invoke the `ExecStop`. This may be doing additional FIFO operations that are hanging, causing the "deactivating" behavior.

You should ensure the `ExecStart` and `ExecStop` commands exit with a zero status and do not hang so that systemd registers the service as inactive.